# Как исправить перегруз GPU-памяти с Tensorflow?

Tags: память, keras, tensorflow, cpu, gpu

Написал модель на Keras, уменьшил изображения, но запускаю код и еще до обучения модели все виснет и выключается комп. Я думаю это из-за GPU-памяти (перегруз), но как исправить не знаю (уменьшил батч - не помогло). Но если я отключу GPU, то на СPU все работает (только медленно). Помогите пж!

Comment: Код в студию. Без кода сложно что-либо сказать, но могу посоветовать уменьшить кол-во нейронов и слоёв. А вообще сомнительно, что из-за переполнения памяти выключается комп. Обычно в таком случае программа падает с ошибкой OOM.

Comment: код не помещается в сообщение). Но если скинуть отрывки то может быть непонятно.

Comment: https://github.com/VitaliyNov/my-code/blob/7c57527a1ba3bba4b135cd96269acedcc8b8baf0/model_keras @V-Mor

Comment: попробуйте, для начала, вдвое (а может и вчетверо) уменьшить кол-во нейронов. Ваша сеть довольна объёмна. А код вставьте в вопрос, чтобы другие участники сообщества тоже могли Вам помочь.